# celery worker not publishing message to the rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have a setup where celery_result_backend has been configured to 'amqp'. I can see my tasks getting executed by the worker in logs. But 
It is creating the queue with task id but its status is expired.I am not getting the result (result = AsyncResult(taskid); result.get() hangs). I tried all the backed supported:
1)Mysql: It is not putting data to the celery created tables
2) Redis: It is not putting data to the db

I two centos system. 
1) I am calling the delay method to send the task to proper rabbitmq. And the worker is listening to the queue, from there it will pick the task and process(I can see task in the queue and getting executed by the worker in machine 2 But the result is not being put into the backend.
).Here I am doing the result.get() It hangs.

2) The worker is running on it to execute the task.It executes the task but I think not able to put the rersult

Settings:

```
RABBITMQ_BROKER_HOST = '10.213.166.133'
RABBITMQ_BROKER_PORT = dqms_settings.RABBITMQ_BROKER_PORT
RABBITMQ_BROKER_VHOST = dqms_settings.RABBITMQ_BROKER_VHOST
RABBITMQ_BROKER_USERNAME = dqms_settings.RABBITMQ_BROKER_USERNAME
RABBITMQ_BROKER_PASSWORD = dqms_settings.RABBITMQ_BROKER_PASSWORD

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (RABBITMQ_BROKER_USERNAME,
                                        RABBITMQ_BROKER_PASSWORD,
                                        RABBITMQ_BROKER_HOST,
                                        RABBITMQ_BROKER_PORT,
                                        RABBITMQ_BROKER_VHOST)

#CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 18000
#CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+mysql://svcacct-dqms:s3cretP@ssw0rd@10.213.166.202:3306/dqms'
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
#CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 1000 
#CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'




CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = dqms_settings.CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = dqms_settings.CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = dqms_settings.CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = dqms_settings.CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY

CELERY_QUEUES = dqms_settings.CELERY_QUEUES
CELERY_ROUTES = dqms_settings.CELERY_ROUTES
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = dqms_settings.CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = dqms_settings.CELERY_ACKS_LATE

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://:s3cretP@ssw0rd@10.213.166.204:6379/5' #'djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'
#CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 6
#CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
```

Can some one help why it is not putting the result in the queue?

Comment: "redis://:s3cretP@ssw0rd@10.213.166.204"... I'd start with a password without "@" (or escaping it)

Comment: escaping it will give error...my passcode is "s3cretP@ssw0rd" now @localhost/db.Am i doing something wrong here

Comment: Passwords with '@' in them are usually a bad idea.  When an URL gets interpreted whatever follows the @ becomes the destination hose so in your case the host as now become "ssw0rd@10.213.166.202"

Comment: May be this one is the issue for redis and mysql but for celery_result_backend='amqp' It is putting expired message in the queue? why is this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue which is happening quite common now.
setting CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER to TRUE will do the work 
However this is not the best solution in production scenario.